# How do I watch a live stream on my iPad?

Tags: ipad, streaming, adobe-flash, vlc

I enjoy watching P2P live streams (Flash) on my iMac and I would like to be able to do the same thing on my iPad. I have tried [Puffin Web Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/puffin-web-browser/id406239138?l=en&mt=8), but the streams that I would like to see are covered in pop-ups with hinky links. On the iMac these will disappear when I go full screen, but within Puffin I can't click that full screen button.

However, I also have [VLC for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vlc-for-ios/id650377962?l=en&mt=8) installed. Is is perhaps possible to watch a P2P live stream via VLC? (I tried Open Network Stream and paste urls there, but that didn't quite work. Perhaps don't know how to pick the right url?)

Can you recommend a set-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puffin Web Browser is not always great for button-like functions within flash content. However, for most flash videos Puffin Web Browser has a "Theater" mode. So in Puffin Web Browser go to the live stream that you would like to view, and wait for it to begin to play. Now, instead of attempting to click the full screen toggle within the player that is showing you the live stream, swipe from the right edge of your screen to bring up the sidebar, and press the "Theater" button. Your video should now be playing in full screen, or as close to full screen as it is going to get. If you really prefer not using Puffin Web Browser, the only version of VLC that fully supports P2P video is the version available on Cydia. If you like stable devices, that is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you. 1. So, no VLC for me. That's good to know. 2. Puffin: "Theater" mode indeed gives the close-to full screen. But, unlike on the iMac, this mode does _not_ remove the "pop-ups" (basically very large blocks the size of half the screen, with links). Any further suggestions?

Comment: I also found the Mouse/Trackpad functionality, which _does_ allow me to click away the ads - if I manage to click them away in the right order. :) But, that's good enough for now. Thanks again.